# Pandas sliding window

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following imported pandas DataFrame indexed by date-time:

```
                             VAL
           DATETIME    
2012-01-02 02:00:00    3.375000
2012-01-02 02:01:00    3.281667
2012-01-02 02:02:00    3.426667
2012-01-02 02:03:00    3.378333
2012-01-02 02:04:00    3.381667
2012-01-02 02:05:00    3.831667
....
```

I need to transform the DataFrame as follows:

```
                            VAL        VAL1        VAL2
           DATETIME    
2012-01-02 02:00:00    3.375000    3.281667    3.426667
2012-01-02 02:01:00    3.281667    3.426667    3.378333
2012-01-02 02:02:00    3.426667    3.378333    3.381667
2012-01-02 02:03:00    3.378333    3.381667    3.831667
...
```

If there any built-in function or an efficient way of achieving this?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) with loop for assign multiple new columns:

```
for x in range(1, 3):
    df['VAL{}'.format(x)] = df['VAL'].shift(-x)
```

If need shift one minute:

```
for x in range(1, 3):
    df['VAL{}'.format(x)] = df['VAL'].shift(-x, freq='T')
```

---

```
print (df)
                          VAL      VAL1      VAL2
DATETIME                                         
2012-01-02 02:00:00  3.375000  3.281667  3.426667
2012-01-02 02:01:00  3.281667  3.426667  3.378333
2012-01-02 02:02:00  3.426667  3.378333  3.381667
2012-01-02 02:03:00  3.378333  3.381667  3.831667
2012-01-02 02:04:00  3.381667  3.831667       NaN
2012-01-02 02:05:00  3.831667       NaN       NaN
```

Last if necessary remove last rows with `NaN`s:

```
#N > 1
N = 3
for x in range(1, N):
    df['VAL{}'.format(x)] = df['VAL'].shift(-x, freq='T')

df = df.iloc[:-N + 1]
print (df)
                          VAL      VAL1      VAL2
DATETIME                                         
2012-01-02 02:00:00  3.375000  3.281667  3.426667
2012-01-02 02:01:00  3.281667  3.426667  3.378333
2012-01-02 02:02:00  3.426667  3.378333  3.381667
2012-01-02 02:03:00  3.378333  3.381667  3.831667
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use NumPy [`stride_tricks`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html):

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.lib.stride_tricks as stride
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'DATETIME': ['2012-01-02 02:00:00', '2012-01-02 02:01:00', '2012-01-02 02:02:00', '2012-01-02 02:03:00', '2012-01-02 02:04:00', '2012-01-02 02:05:00'], 'VAL': [3.375, 3.2816669999999997, 3.4266669999999997, 3.378333, 3.3816669999999998, 3.831667]})
df['DATETIME']  = pd.to_datetime(df['DATETIME'])
df = df.set_index('DATETIME')


stride = df['VAL'].values.strides[0]
ncols = 3
nrows = len(df)-ncols+1
arr = stride.as_strided(df['VAL'], shape=(nrows, ncols), strides=(stride, stride))

result = pd.DataFrame(arr.copy(), columns=['VAL{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, ncols+1)],
                      index=df.index[:nrows])
```

yields

```
                         VAL1      VAL2      VAL3
DATETIME                                         
2012-01-02 02:00:00  3.375000  3.281667  3.426667
2012-01-02 02:01:00  3.281667  3.426667  3.378333
2012-01-02 02:02:00  3.426667  3.378333  3.381667
2012-01-02 02:03:00  3.378333  3.381667  3.831667
```

---

`strides=(stride,stride)` is the key to making the sliding windows. It tells
`stride.as_strided` that at each location in `result` the next value to the
right (i.e. in the next column) is `stride` bytes away and each value down
(i.e. in the next row) is also only `stride` bytes away. The bytes defining the
values in `result` are taken from the underlying array, `arr.copy()`.

---

While `stride_tricks` can produce the desired array very quickly, 
there are caveats related to its use. See below and the [Notes on the doc page](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html).
Those caveats are entirely mitigated by copying the array -- i.e. using `arr.copy()` instead of `arr` itself. 
On the other hand, copying the array, particularly if it is large, reduces performance.

---

Note that if you use `pd.DataFrame(arr)` instead of `pd.DataFrame(arr.copy())`,
then the values in the DataFrame are a *view* of `df['VAL']`. While this is memory-efficient, it also means that modifying one value in `result` can change the value in multiple locations. For example,

```
result = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=['VAL{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, ncols+1)],
                      index=df.index[:nrows])

In [30]: result.iloc[1,1] = 100
In [27]: result
Out[27]: 
                           VAL1        VAL2        VAL3
DATETIME                                               
2012-01-02 02:00:00    3.375000    3.281667  100.000000
2012-01-02 02:01:00    3.281667  100.000000    3.378333
2012-01-02 02:02:00  100.000000    3.378333    3.381667
2012-01-02 02:03:00    3.378333    3.381667    3.831667
```

If you wish each value to be independent, use `arr.copy()`.